# appsettings.json and token substitution in github actions

Tags: .net, configuration, github-actions

I'm trying to build and deploy a .NET 6 app using Github actions.

I have a job that build and test the app and produce an .zip artifact with the app bundle, the artifact contains the traditional appsettings.json.

On the next deployment jobs I want to replace some of the variables in the appsettings.json with variables from environment, repository and organisation secrets.

Any recommendations?
I saw there was an official [action](https://github.com/microsoft/variable-substitution) from Microsoft for this, but it is now deprecated.
Do you know if there is an official or accepted way for this? One option is to implement an own solution, but seems is such a common thing that I doubt I need to go and implememt this again?